# Trouble initializing a java project in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

(Note: to anyone downvoting, kindly tell me the reason so I can improve and not repeat it)

I followed the instructions given in Java Getting Started inside vscode, but it resulted in failure. I do not just want a, perhaps hacky, fix for this. I want to understand what is causing the problem.

I am on Ubuntu 19.04 64bit.
vscode version 1.38.1
I have all the basic java extensions included in the pack installed in vscode.
java --version returns :

```
java 12.0.2 2019-07-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

This is what I followed.
[image: getting-started]

It first took me to the newly generated launch.json instead of directly running the code as stated in the procedure.
Here is my launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch) - Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch)-QuickStart",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "QuickStart"
        }
    ]
}
```

I went ahead and hit F5 on my file again and this is what I was met with

```sh
user@machine:$ cd /home/user/test/java/proj ; /usr/lib/jvm/java-12-oracle/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:42535 --enable-preview -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp /home/user/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/db4b3a82ff379b93685473884410762c/redhat.java/jdt_ws/jdt.ls-java-project/bin QuickStart 
Error: Could not find or load main class QuickStart
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: QuickStart
```

Please help me understand this and thereby fix it.
If I have missed out any crucial information, please ask in the comments and I will promptly add it.

Thank you

Comment: class should be `public`, shouldn't it?

Comment: True, i added a public in front, no change in result though.

Answer (score -1):

There might be two reason to not identifying Java

1.Might be java is not installed correctly

2.Or there are multiple version jdk installed so might be conflict

you could refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58127113/10768653)

Comment: It was a bug in the vscode extension. One they fixed a week ago and will be released soon. Should i still answer my own question and accept it?

Thanks anyway!